# How to strip object down to specific fields elegantly?

Tags: javascript

I want to remove all excessive fields but the ones I specify from an object. How can I do that elegantly. Eg.: I want something like:

```
let obj = {email: 'test', id: 'someid', password: 'pas'}

stripObject(obj, 'email', 'id')

//now obj contains only email & id
```

Comment: `stripObject(obj, email, id)` What do the `email` and `id` variables contain? Did you mean to pass strings instead? Have you tried writing any code yet?

Comment: please add the result and your try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Array.map" and "Object.assign" for this task as below

```js
let obj = {email: 'test', id: 'someid', password: 'pas'}

function stripObject(obj , ...args) {
  return Object.assign(...args.map(d => ({ [d]: obj[d] })))
}

console.log(stripObject(obj, 'email', 'id'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
let obj = {email: 'test', id: 'someid', password: 'pas'}

function stripObject(obj, ...args) {
  let newObj = {};
  args.forEach(arg => {
    newObj[arg] = obj[arg];
  });
  return newObj;
}

let stripped = stripObject(obj, 'email', 'id');
console.log(stripped);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gjm0L2vw/